window.addEventListener('load',... does not trigger on Chrome on iOS (iPad)
We are using identity Server 4.
We are using .NET Core RazorPages web-applications.
They authenticate via openid-connect
While authentificating,the client is redirected to a html page with a hidden form that is submitted when the page has loaded.
Here is the code of this page:
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<base target='_self'/>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action='http://localhost:58643/signin-oidc'>
<input type='hidden' name='id_token' value='eyJhbGciOi...' /> (Token is cut of in this example)
<input type='hidden' name='scope' value='openid profile ccentre' />
<input type='hidden' name='state' value='CfDJ8JVWRhTCuH9D...' /> (Token is cut of in this example)
<input type='hidden' name='session_state' value='xKpaG_OnBJzsxWy2EZoo85BNjduPDts6gYelBoaSRps.9E11974BFE68940C61EB05DF0EE6C798' />
<noscript><button>Click to continue</button></noscript></form><script>window.addEventListener('load', function(){document.forms[0].submit();});</script>

On iOS devices the submit is not executed at random times. First on Safai and Chrome. But the problem vanished slowly in the safari-browser and now only remains in the chrome browser. There it appears every 4. or 5. try.
The Device where the error appeares uses iOS 17.4.1
The Chrome browser is Version 125.0.6422.80
We cannot reproduce this behaviour with our devices. It only happens on the devices of a customer on a remote place.
We debugged in a teams-session with the remote IT on a mac at the remote location
With several tools like Wireshark we could trace the error to the described point, not triggering the event.
But there were no JS-error-messages in the browser-console (debugged via USB-Debugging on a mac)
Greetings and thank you for your suggestions.
